# Capturing 'semi'- tagged text

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Sorry about the formatting, 'long-time lurker, first time poster'....

Myself and another programmer have been working on this, and tried many permutations. What I am wanting to capture is that last 'This is untagged text outside bar' line... 
Not sure how to better describe the tagging, but I am receiving an XML block structured like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <text>
    <inlineTag name="bar">
    <inlineTag name="text">
        <inlineTag name="strong">
            THIS IS A SIDEBAR BOX
        </inlineTag>
    </inlineTag>`
    <break type="paragraph"/>
    <break type="paragraph"/>
    This is untagged text inside bar.
    </inlineTag>
     This is untagged text outside bar
    </text>
```

I run it against this xslt:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template name="Untagged_Bar" match="text()[parent::node()/@name='bar']">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::text() and string-length(.) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:element name="p">
                <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'k4text'"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="bold" match="//inlineTag[@name='strong']">
    <xsl:element name="strong">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

And I get this, which is ALMOST what I want...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
     <p class="k4text">
     </p>
     <strong>
      THIS IS A SIDEBAR BOX
      </strong>
      <p class="k4text">
      </p>
    <p class="k4text">
    </p>
    <p class="k4text">
    This is untagged text inside bar.
    </p>
    This is untagged text outside bar
    </root>
```

What I want is more like THIS:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <root>
      <p class="k4text">
      <strong>
       THIS IS A SIDEBAR BOX
      </strong>
      </p>
      <p class="k4text">
      This is untagged text inside bar.
      </p>
      <p class="k4text">
      This is untagged text outside bar
      </p>
    </root>
```

What am I missing? I had another xslt guy here at work look at it, and we tried MANY permutations, and this is the closest we can get, but we still can't that last

```
   <p class="k4text">
    This is untagged text outside bar
    </p>
```

to come out correct... any thoughts/help/suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide a different, much more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//text()[normalize-space()]"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="current-text" select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="h">
    <xsl:with-param name="current-text" select="$current-text" tunnel="yes"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="h">
  <xsl:param name="current-text" tunnel="yes"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[descendant-or-self::node() intersect $current-text]" mode="h"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="inlineTag[@name = 'strong']" mode="h">
  <xsl:param name="current-text" tunnel="yes"/>
  <strong>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[descendant-or-self::node() intersect $current-text]" mode="h"/>
  </strong>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@name = 'bar']" mode="h">
  <xsl:param name="current-text" tunnel="yes"/>
  <p class="k4text">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[descendant-or-self::node() intersect $current-text]" mode="h"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[not(ancestor::*[@name = 'bar'])]" mode="h">
  <p class="k4text">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <text>
    <inlineTag name="bar">
    <inlineTag name="text">
        <inlineTag name="strong">
            THIS IS A SIDEBAR BOX
        </inlineTag>
    </inlineTag>
    <break type="paragraph"/>
    <break type="paragraph"/>
    This is untagged text inside bar.
    </inlineTag>
     This is untagged text outside bar
    </text>
```

into the result

```
<root>
   <p class="k4text">
      <strong>
            THIS IS A SIDEBAR BOX
        </strong>
   </p>
   <p class="k4text">
    This is untagged text inside bar.
    </p>
   <p class="k4text">
     This is untagged text outside bar
    </p>
</root>
```

I think the above solution is expensive with all those `node()[descendant-or-self::node() intersect $current-text]` checks. Therefore I post a different approach that simply computes the nodes once we need to rebuild for each text node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//text()[normalize-space()]"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="nodes" select="ancestor-or-self::node() except /"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodes[1]" mode="h">
    <xsl:with-param name="remaining-nodes" select="$nodes[position() gt 1]" tunnel="yes"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="h">
  <xsl:param name="remaining-nodes" tunnel="yes"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$remaining-nodes[1]" mode="h">
    <xsl:with-param name="remaining-nodes" select="$remaining-nodes[position() gt 1]" tunnel="yes"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="inlineTag[@name = 'strong']" mode="h">
  <xsl:param name="remaining-nodes" tunnel="yes"/>
  <strong>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$remaining-nodes[1]" mode="h">
      <xsl:with-param name="remaining-nodes" select="$remaining-nodes[position() gt 1]" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </strong>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@name = 'bar']" mode="h">
  <xsl:param name="remaining-nodes" tunnel="yes"/>
  <p class="k4text">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$remaining-nodes[1]" mode="h">
      <xsl:with-param name="remaining-nodes" select="$remaining-nodes[position() gt 1]" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[not(ancestor::*[@name = 'bar'])]" mode="h">
  <p class="k4text">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should be the same but the code should be much more efficient.